# Twitter live feed on ArcGIS desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gps, twitter

I am a complete beginner with ArcGIS and I have been looking for a way to live feed tweets to ArcGIS desktop. A quick google search brings this blogpost up from 2009: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/12/15/arcgis-explorer-and-geo-service-integration-twitter-add-in/

However, the link to the add-on is dead. Does this add-on still exist? If so, does anyone know where. If not, does anyone know why?